# Facebook AppDelegate does not implement the 'FBSessionDelegate' protocol

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

Hey developers,
I am trying to implement the Facebook iOS into my Xcode project. I followed the Facebook tutorial on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#ios, now after implementing the code, I get the

> Class 'FacebookSampleAppDelegate' does not implement the 'FBSessionDelegate' protocol

I hope someone can help me out with this small problem, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add FBSessionDelegate to the interface of `FacebookSampleAppDelegate` to declare that your Class conforms to the `FBSessionDelegate` protocol.

```
@interface FacebookSampleAppDelegate : NSObject <FBSessionDelegate> {
```

if there is already a protocol present just add your own like this:

```
<UIApplicationDelegate, FBSessionDelegate>
```

Comment: wow thanks! it works! Now i have just a minor problem, yes it's showing the app, but the problem is that it's showing the address bar on top and a web controller at the bottom, how do I get rid of them to just show the facebook app? (sorry for my bad english)

Comment: You should create a new question. I have no idea about FaceBook sdk. I've downloaded it but I never even looked inside. The answer I gave you works for every other protocol too, that's the only reason I could answer it :-)

Comment: oh and please stop to apologize for your bad english. It's not bad at all.

Comment: I can't do that it says cannot find protocol decleration for FBSessionDelegate. I imported "#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>"